# How can I pass a value to messages in ng-messages?

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I wrote a custom validation using ng-messages. For example here is a greater than validation:

```
(function (module) {
    module.directive('greaterThanValidator', function () {
            return {
                require: ['ngModel'],
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    var data = attrs.greaterThanValidator;
                    ngModel.$validators.greaterThan = function (value) {

                        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && !isNaN(parseFloat(data))) {
                            value = parseFloat(value);
                            data = parseFloat(data);
                        }

                        if (!value || value.length == 0) {
                            element.$setValidity('greaterThan', true);
                        } else if (value>data) {
                            element.$setValidity('greaterThan', true);
                        } else {
                            element.$setValidity('greaterThan', false);
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    );
})(angular.module("lego.base"));
```

This is my message `div`s:

```
<div class="error-messages" ng-if="..."
     ng-messages="form.field.$error">
    <div ng-message="greaterThan">Your value should be greater than {{number}}</div>
</div>
```

How do I pass the `number` to messages content?

`Edit:`

usage is as below:

```
<input ng-model="something" greater-than-validator="100">
```

Comment: Btw, is the `ngModel.$validators.graterThan = function (value)` a typo (`graterThan`)?  This doesn't affect getting the value into the message, but it will prevent the message from appearing at all.

Comment: see the developer guide on directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive -- in the directive, define the scope and map the scope to your controller value (I am assuming number is defined in your controller)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Sorry, the typo occurred when I wrote the question, but my code works correct

Comment: @water42 see the added section in question. number is passed by developers

Comment: You will have to set number in controller and then `<input ng-model="something" greater-than-validator="{{ number }}">`.

Comment: @dfsq yes but I should require ngController in validation directive, but if user does not used ng-controller and used the input inside of a `component`, your solution does not work

Comment: What? No, you don't need to require ngController in your directive, why? I'm saying set number in page controller, not directive controller.

Comment: @dfsq We didn't use scope in our controllers , we have bound everything to  `this` of controllers. And also we don't know where the validation directive have used

Comment: So bind number to controller, doesn't matter.